# How do I group these objects into those that can be linked to each other?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, matching, excel-365

I have a list of items and matches that have been found, like this.

| item | matches |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | tree;window |  |
| box | microscope |  |
| chimney | dish;fence |  |
| dish |  |  |
| fence |  |  |
| headphones |  |  |
| microscope | box;headphones |  |
| painting |  |  |
| window | chimney;apple |  |

I want to put them into groups, where every object that can be 'reached' by another object is in the same group as that object. So for example, *apple* is in the same group as *fence* because, in the 'matches' column, we can go *apple -> window -> chimney -> fence*.

However, *apple* is not in the same group as *microscope* because there is no path between the two. They don't list each other in the 'matches' column, and none of those items list the other item in its 'matches' column, and so on.

| item | matches | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | tree;window | 1 |
| box | microscope | 2 |
| chimney | dish;fence | 1 |
| dish |  | 1 |
| fence |  | 1 |
| headphones |  | 2 |
| microscope | box;headphones | 2 |
| painting |  | 3 |
| window | chimney;apple | 1 |

^This is what the third column, *group,* should look like. Is there a way I can do this with a LAMBDA function, preferably without addins?

Something like TEXTJOIN will not work, as despite a 'path' existing, no string match will connect 'apple' and 'chimney' because a match doesn't exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=XMATCH("*"&A2&"*",REDUCE(,A$1:A10,LAMBDA(m,n,IF(COUNT(FIND(n,m)),m,VSTACK(m,REDUCE(n,A2:A10,LAMBDA(x,y,TEXTJOIN(";",,x,XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(x,";"),A:A,B:B,"")))))))),2)-1
```

[image]

Comment: This works as asked, thank you. Could you explain a little about how it works? I'm still struggling to get my head around Lambda functions, tbh.

Answer (score 1):

```
=MIN(
    IFNA(
        VLOOKUP("*"&
            LET(
                Z,LAMBDA(X,UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,REPT(A$2:B$10,BYROW(A$2:A$10&B$2:B$10,LAMBDA(S,COUNT(FIND(X,S))>0)))),,";"))),
                Z(Z(Z(Z(A2)))))&"*",
                IF({1,0},A$1:A$1&B$1:B1,C$1:C1),2,),9),N(C1)+1)
```

[image]

Z split level, I added two more to prevent accidents, just for reference.